# Can we use multiple authentication methods in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, single-sign-on, saml

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project, we have username/password authentication already implemented. We are trying to add SAML authentication (Azure AD) to the project. Is that possible? Can these two authentication methods co-exist in the same project? If so how can I implement that?

This is my current startup class:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies

Public Class Startup 
Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)

Dim timeoutKey As Integer = Integer.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("timeOut"))

app.CreatePerOwinContext(Function() New Entities())
app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of UserManager)(Function() UserManager.Create(Nothing, HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext())) 'CTNOTE: I had to modify this... Keep an eye on it.
app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of RoleManager(Of Role))(Function(options, context) New RoleManager(Of Role)(New RoleStore(Of Role)(context.Get(Of Entities)())))


app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
    .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
        .OnResponseSignIn = Sub(context)
                              context.Properties.AllowRefresh = True
                              context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(timeoutKey)
                            End Sub
    },
    .SlidingExpiration = True,
    .CookieName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("cookie"),
    .CookieHttpOnly = True,
    .CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
    .CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
    .ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeoutKey),
    .LoginPath = New PathString("default"),
    .LogoutPath = New PathString("default"),
    .ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnTo"}
    )
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm following this SSO integration tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/saml-toolkit-tutorial , but I don't know how to make it work with the form  authentication method I already have in the project.

The project is not ASP.NET Core.